# Cast child object to parent in dragged object - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Can we cast child object to it's parent when child is being dragged from one container to another? Here is what I am trying to do.

1. I have a list box having the objects of Derived class 1 and Derived class 2.
2. When I drag Derived class 1 object and try to drop at another list box, the object I get is of the type Derived Class 1. Similarly it's Derived Class 2 when I drag Derived Class 2 object.

While dropping at the another list box which has ItemSource binded to ObservableCollection, I want to cast these derived class objects to Base Class.

Note: I get null when I use Base Class with typeof operator with dragged object.

Here is my XAML

```
<GroupBox Header="BaseClassObjects" >
        <ListBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding BaseClassList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="protocol_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        </ListBox>
    </GroupBox>





  <GroupBox Header="Drop Here" >
                <ListBox AllowDrop="True" Drop="ports_Drop">
                </ListBox>
            </GroupBox>
```

Binded properties in View model

```
ObservableCollection<BaseClass> baseClassList = new ObservableCollection<BaseClass>();

        public ObservableCollection<BaseClass> BaseClassList
        {
            get { return baseClassList; }
            set { baseClassList = value; }
        }

 public VM_DragDrop()
        {
            BaseClassList.Add(new DerivedClassOne() { Name = "Derived Class 1" });
            BaseClassList.Add(new DerivedClassTwo() { Name = "Derived Class 2" });
        }
```

Base and Derived classes

```
  public class BaseClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedClassOne : BaseClass
    {

    }

    public class DerivedClassTwo : BaseClass
    {

    }
```

Event handlers in xaml.cs file

```
private void protocol_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox listbox = (sender as ListBox);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listbox, listbox.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

 private void ports_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            BaseClass droppedObject = (BaseClass)(e.Data.GetData(typeof(BaseClass)));
            (sender as ListBox).Items.Add(droppedObject);

    }
```

Here the droppedObject will be null whenever I drag Derived Class 1 or Derived Class 2 since Data what we get with dragged object is either DerivedClassOne or DerivedClassTwo.

Please suggest how can we cast these derived objects to parent while dropping.

Comment: Could you see the contents of `e.Data` while debugging?

Comment: Yes. I could see the dragged object information in e.Data. i.e. When I drag 'Derived Class 1', I see 'DerivedClassOne' in e.Data

Answer (score 0):

DragEventArgs have a [.GetFormats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557793(v=vs.110).aspx) function returning an array of strings, with each string specifying the name of a format supported by this data object.

Then you can use this string for pick up and convert drop data content:

```
Dim tmpTypes() As String = e.Data.GetFormats
Dim tmpTyp As String = tmpTypes(0)
Dim dropper As MyObjectBase = TryCast(e.Data.GetData(tmpTyp), MyObjectBase)
```

You get yours Base object or nothing... Without exact test of all known derived classes.